# Unable to send Token in Stripe with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, stripe-payments

The Error I am getting when I try to checkout after putting card details:

Invalid source object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string. See API docs at [https://stripe.com/docs'](https://stripe.com/docs%27)

Here I taking all the card information:

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('checkout')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="checkout-form">
@csrf
<div class="col-sm-3">
   <div class="form-group">
       <label>Card Number*</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="card-number" id="card-number" placeholder="4111 1111 1111 1111"> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Card CVC*</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="card-cvc" id="card-cvc" placeholder="111"> </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Card Expiry Month*</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" name="card-month" id="card-month" placeholder="12"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-3">
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Card Expiry Year*</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="card-expiry-year" id="card-expiry-year" placeholder="2020"> </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
           <label>Card Name*</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="card-name" id="card-name" placeholder="John"> </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

I am sending the Token through script:

```
<script>
var stripe = Stripe('test_key');

var $form = $('#checkout-form');

$form.submit(function (event) {
    $('charge-error').addClass('hidden');
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled' , true);
    Stripe.card.createToken({
        number: $('.card-number').val(),
        cvc: $('.card-cvc').val(),
        exp_month: $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
        exp_year: $('.card-expiry-year').val(),
        name: $('.card-name').val(),

    }, stripeResponseHandler);
    return false;
});

function stripeResponseHandler(status, response) {

    var $form = $('#checkout-form');

    if (response.error){
        $('.charge-error').removeClass('hidden');
        $('.charge-error').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        var token = response.id;
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

        //Submit the form:
        $form.get(0).submit();
    }
}
```

and this is the controller Function:

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient('secret_test_key');
    try {
        $charge = $stripe->charges->create([
                "amount" => 6800,
                "currency" => "usd",
                "source" => $request->input('stripeToken'),
                "description" => "Charge for test@expamle.com"
            ]
        );
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return redirect()->route('checkout')->with('error', $e->getMessage());
    }
```

If the replace the "source" => $request->input('stripeToken'), with "source" => "visa", then the code works fine.

Why am I getting this error? Please help.

Comment: i think stripe v3 is updated now you have to use like this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing#payment-methods

Answer (score 0):

At the line where you have `"source" => $request->input('stripeToken')` try to print that input out before carrying out the charge to see if the value is actually there or is in a valid format. If the value is not there ensure the variable you have called token assigned to the hidden field actually has the correct value.

Comment: I tried to print this variable and it's empty. I don't know what is the mistake.

Comment: Yeah. I knew it must be empty so that's the issue stripe has with it. Now check if the value you pass to the hidden field in the js script is actually correct.

Comment: I tried to print the var token in console through script. but it shows nothing. Response.id is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Stripe.js v2 you need to set the publishable key like this:

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey('pk_test_xxx');
```

not what you're currently doing:

```
var stripe = Stripe('test_key');
```

(see https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/v2#setting-publishable-key)

Comment: I used Stripe.setPublishableKey but it gives error in console that it's not a function.

Comment: Ah, then you must be using v3 already. Then you need to change `Stripe.card.createToken` to use the v3 version (https://stripe.com/docs/js/tokens_sources/create_token?type=cardElement). There's a migration guide here: https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/elements/migrating#securely-collect-card-details